# Sets and bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked to do determine if the following set is countable and if so, perform a bijection with the Natural set of numbers.

The set is: all bit strings not containing the bit $0$

I have determined that this is a countable set. Performing the bijection is the part I am unsure of.

My first thought is to write $\{1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, \ldots\}$ but is this actually a valid answer? Any suggestions on what technique I would use to show a valid answer?

Comment: Hint: What is different about two distinct bit strings in the collection?

Comment: To be precise you want to have an actual function from the set of such bit string to the set of natural numbers. Now, can you think of some characteristic of a bit string without 0's that completely determines what that bit string is? perhaps a natural number that does the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on your way:

Note that given the set you are constructing, we have:

$$A = \{\underbrace{1}_{\large n = 1}, \underbrace{11}_{\large n = 2}, \underbrace{111}_{\large n = 3}, \underbrace{1111}_{\large n = 4}, \underbrace{11111}_{\large n = 5}, \underbrace{\cdots}_{\large \ldots} \}$$

Now, can you find a way to construct, or define, a bijective function $f: A \to \mathbb N$ (or equivalently, a bijective function $g: \mathbb N \to A$)?

Comment: Always reminds me of cantor diagonalization

Comment: I can see the mapping, but unfortunately am unsure how to create a function to define this. Specifically how to show that there are x number of ones for a given x.

Comment: A function can be defined in words; there are many ways to define a function: you'd be looking to send $n \to$ concantenation (a string) of $n$ $1$'s (a bit string of 1's of length n)

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I see what I can do.

Comment: You're welcome. Nice work!

Comment: @amWhy: nice formatting! :-) +1 So SLOW ...

Comment: It is so very, very slow! Chat...reviewing...posts...all slow...big sigh!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
$$f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}10^{k}$$

Comment: Could you explain where it fails to meet the criteria?  It must be 1-1 since $f$ is clearly increasing. So then it fails surjectivity somehow? Are you just saying I need to rewrite it as $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}10^k$$ so that the domain is the positive integers?

Comment: Brain glitch.  You are right.  The lower limit is not a big deal.

Comment: Phew. That's good to hear.